# Unable to run hadoop jar - incorrect number of arguments

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I am new to Hadoop and followed a WordCount MapReduce example that I found online to run in Ubuntu. I managed to complete all but the final step - i.e. running the job. I uploaded the input file to the cluster and my input file directory is /user/inputdata/test.txt and I intend on using the /user/output directory for the file. With that being said I ran the following command

```
hadoop jar /home/wasim/Downloads/jar_files/MapReduceDemo.jar MapReduceDemo.WordCounter /user/inputdata/test.txt /user/output
```

however, when I receive the following error

> usage: WordCount <input_file> <output_directory>

I know this error stems from my java to ensure that I have the correct arguments when running the hadoop jar. I've tried to the command in several other ways but keep on getting the same error. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
package MapReduceDemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class WordCounter {
    
    public static class TokenizeMapper extends Mapper<Object,Text,Text,IntWritable>{
        
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            Text wordOut = new Text();
            IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                wordOut.set(st.nextToken());
                context.write(wordOut, one);
                
            }       
        }
    }
    
    public static class SumReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>{
        public void reduce(Text term,Iterable<IntWritable> ones, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int count = 0;
            Iterator<IntWritable> iterator = ones.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                count++;
                iterator.next();
            }
            IntWritable output = new IntWritable(count);
            context.write(term, output);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        
        if(otherArgs.length !=2) {
            System.err.println("usage: WordCount <input_file> <output_directory>");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf,"Word Count");
        job.setJarByClass(WordCounter.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizeMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(SumReducer.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(10);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(otherArgs[1]));
        boolean status = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        if(status) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's your own error that you're printing `if (otherArgs.length !=2) {`, you should debug there and see what args you're actually getting.

Comment: A confusing error message (`WordCount` is not the name of your class) but normally speaking, you should be doing something more like: `java -cp /home/wasim/Downloads/jar_files/MapReduceDemo.jar MapReduceDemo.WordCounter /user/inputdata/test.txt /user/output` or `java -jar /home/wasim/Downloads/jar_files/MapReduceDemo.jar /user/inputdata/test.txt /user/output`

Comment: @g00se That's not how to submit mapreduce applications to Hadoop.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Right - I wasn't sure about that, as I have not used hadoop. If all those tokens are in the normal run of Hadoop then I can't see that being the *actual* command, since there *are* two arguments being passed to the app. Either that or Hadoop is not passing them to the app

Comment: @g00se It's correct. `hadoop jar <file.jar> <class> [args...]`

Comment: Thanks for everyone's response. I found the error. I saved the .jar file as runnable jar file, instead of a jar file. Now I am able to run the command.

Comment: Strange that Hadoop would care that it's executable. You gave it the full path to the jar and the f.q. name of the main class.